# Understanding arrays and the use of operators

Tags: swift

[image][image]

I've included a photo of what I'm working on. I'm learning to code using swift playgrounds on the iPad. I'm up to arrays. In the photo I'm to build an island and add a body of water. I'm not sure if you need the entire code to understand my question. (The bottom part of the code just removes some of the land and adds water)

My question is for the part where the greater than and less than operators are being used. I don't understand what coordinate.column > 3 actually means.

If you need more info I can upload another photo with the final product and complete code.

I've added another photo of the final product and it has the remainder code with it as well. I understand that < means less than and > means greater than. But there are no columns that are less than 3 in the final product or a row greater than 8 so what makes the use of the operators work to get the water to surround the island?

Comment: If the coordinate's column is greater (bigger) than 3 and the coordinate's column is less (smaller) than 8 and ...

Comment: Thanks Charles it wouldn't let me embed photos yet.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would recommend reading the Basic Operators section of the language guide, where [the comparison operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) are explained.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the function goes through each of the tiles of your continent grid and decides if it should be kept as land (added to the island array) or transformed into water) (added to the sea array).
Let's say that your top left tile is of coordinate (0,0) (column 0 and row 0), then it goes as sea, now let's take tile (3,3), it still goes as sea as the comparison is strict (>3 not >=3), tile (5,7) is going in island and tile (8,9) is going in sea.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's worth mentioning that `column` and `row` properties are numbers (of type `Int` - natural (whole) numbers).

The field is represented by a grid, in your case 11x11. Each block has a two-dimensional coordinate within that grid, represented by aforementioned column and row properties.

Indexes in Swift start from 0, so when you iterate over all blocks, their column and row values can be essentially numbers from 0 to 10.

Now, what you want to do is to select bricks in the middle of the grid. If you want the island to be 4 blocks in size each dimension, you do that by comparing their coordinates. Essentially, "island in the middle of size 4 bricks each dimension" is a collection of bricks located at coordinates 4,4; 4,5; 4,6; 4,7; 5,4; 5,5; ...., 7,7. 
That "if" condition that you have is merely a good way of selecting these bricks.

Comment: Edited the answer, had a few typos first.

Comment: Thank you so much this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The > and < symbols are boolean operators, so here I am assuming that coordinate.column would return a number, and then it'll be compared for either > or < and then return true if in fact coordinate.column is < or > 8 and 3 respectively.

Comment: Hi I've added another photo with the final solution as well as the remainder code. If coordinate.column is greater than 3 and less than 8 and the same is true for column.row why is there a 4 by 4 grid of island surrounded by the water.

Comment: `The > and < symbols are boolean operators in Swift.` And virtually any other language.

Comment: @CashmereTatum It's >3 and <8, the only values possible are 4,5,6,7.  Those rows and columns will be the only coordinates that get land.  Any other value (1,2,3,8) would make the if statement false and make the coordinate sea since it'd trigger the else clause.

Comment: Oookay now I get it. Thanks

Comment: If you find the solution to your answer, click the green checkmark under the post that answered it to mark your question as answered.